# Hardware communication fails after ros::init

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear list,

I've a couple of packages for communicating with our delta robot. This is sample code, it's ugly, but it's for demonstration purposes only:

```
....
std::cout << "par_trajectory_planning." << std::endl;
ros::init(argc, argv, "par_trajectory_planning");
//ros::NodeHandle n;
modbus_t* ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS0", 115200, 'N', 8, 1); 
//init_communication(ctx);
//configure_PTP_motion(ctx);
par_trajectory_planning::commands cmd;
cmd.xyz_pos.clear();
stepperMotor = new StepperMotor(ctx);
stepperMotor->initCom();
cmd.xyz_pos.push_back(-41.5733);
cmd.xyz_pos.push_back(-41.5733);
cmd.xyz_pos.push_back(-41.5733);
stepperMotor->confPTPMotion(cmd);
...
```

If i run this program with the following command:

```
rosrun par_trajectory_planning par_planning
```

It seems to block the hardware. I get messages like the following:

```
ANGLE: -41.5733
[03][10][04][02][00][02][04][00][00][02][A1][8B][D6]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<03><10><04><02><00><02><E0><DA>
errno: File exists
```

There errno is the problem. If i disable this line in the sample code:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "par_trajectory_planning");
```

The program works as expected; we start it with the same command. Of course no ROS integration, but it communicates with the hardware as expected. What happens in ros::init that alters the behavior of our program? We make use of libmodbus ([www.libmodbus.org](http://www.libmodbus.org)) in this package and it works fine; but if we integrate it in ROS it doesn't work.

I tried to start everything as root, but that doesn't change errors. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9954/hardware-communication-fails-after-ros::init/) by [Wouter van Teijlingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/77/wouter-van-teijlingen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-17**:
Total shot in the dark: ros::init edits argc and argv; are you possibly sending command-line arguments that look like ROS arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're going to need to find the very first point at which execution diverges from the working and nonworking versions.  At this point you could ask, "why does ros::init change this specific behavior", but with what is here it is hard to say.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0